# JShell short-cut for going at the start of line and going at the end of line

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

is there any short-cut available for moving the cursor at the start of a line and at the end of the line? Rather than moving arrow left and right can we use any shortcut for the same?

Comment: like 'home' and 'end'? Those should work in jshell

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) The answer, *"A lot. An absurd amount. More than you think you are capable of. After you have reached the end of your rope and the pain of not having the answer exceeds the vast amount of shame received by posting your question, that's when you can go ahead and ask. Because at that point, you will have done whatever research necessary to make it a good question worth asking!"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one's from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jshell.htm#JSWOR-GUID-C337353B-074A-431C-993F-60C226163F00):

> The editing capabilities of JShell are similar to that of other common
>   shells. Keyboard keys and key combinations provide line editing
>   shortcuts. The `Ctrl` key and `Meta` key are used in key combinations. If
>   your keyboard doesn’t have a `Meta` key, then the `Alt` key is often
>   mapped to provide Meta key functionality.

You can use:

```
Ctrl+A
```

to move the cursor to the beginning of the line and

```
Ctrl+E
```

to move the cursor to the end of the line.